Spring batch jpaPagingItemReader Read Map from for step context and apply to queryString's inclause using xml configuration
Below is my step configuration. productIds is a HashMap attached to Step Execution Context
<bean id="readCustomer" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaPagingItemReader" scope="step"><property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/><property name="queryString" value="select c from Customer c 
  where c.startDate &gt; :fromDate and c.endDate &lt;= :toDate 
  and c.productId in (:productIds)"/><property name="pageSize" value="1000"/><property name="parameterValues">
  <map>
      <entry key="fromDate" value="#{stepExecutionContext[fromDate]}"/>
      <entry key="toDate" value="#{stepExecutionContext[toDate]}"/>
      <entry key="productIds" value="#{stepExecutionContext[productIds]}"/>
  </map></property></bean>

How do I pass list of product ids in order to filter records for all those product ids
This works for one product id passed to step Execution context as String. I would like to know how to pass and read multiple productIds.
